# Android fragment not inflating

Tags: java, android, fragment, layout-inflater

I am just trying to inflate a simple fragment for a newsreader project that uses an RSS feed to display news stories. The task is simply to convert the activities to fragments and retain functionality. I have been trying for days to get this to work.

The only goal right now is to get the fragment to inflate and display a test button, a textview and an empty listview. I have checked the fragment XML dozens of times and found no errors. As far as I understand displaying fragment_items in ActivityItems should work. I am performing this inflation exactly as my textbook describes how to inflate a fragment to no avail. I have tried googling every line of the logcat and reading through as many threads as possible and haven't found a solution yet.

**ItemsActivity.java**

```
package com.murach.newsreader;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class ItemsActivity extends Activity {

private RSSFeed feed;
private FileIO io;

private TextView titleTextView;
private ListView itemsListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_items);

    io = new FileIO(getApplicationContext());

    titleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
    itemsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemsListView);
}

class DownloadFeed extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        io.downloadFile();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Log.d("News reader", "Feed downloaded");
        new ReadFeed().execute();
    }
}

class ReadFeed extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        feed = io.readFile();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Log.d("News reader", "Feed read");

        // update the display for the activity
        ItemsActivity.this.updateDisplay();
    }
}

public void updateDisplay()
{
    if (feed == null) {
        titleTextView.setText("Unable to get RSS feed");
        return;
    }

    // set the title for the feed
    titleTextView.setText(feed.getTitle());

    // get the items for the feed
    ArrayList<RSSItem> items = feed.getAllItems();

    // create a List of Map<String, ?> objects
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data =
            new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    for (RSSItem item : items) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("date", item.getPubDateFormatted());
        map.put("title", item.getTitle());
        data.add(map);
    }

    // create the resource, from, and to variables
    int resource = R.layout.listview_item;
    String[] from = {"date", "title"};
    int[] to = {R.id.pubDateTextView, R.id.titleTextView};

    // create and set the adapter
    SimpleAdapter adapter =
            new SimpleAdapter(this, data, resource, from, to);
    itemsListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    Log.d("News reader", "Feed displayed");
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                        int position, long id) {

    // get the item at the specified position
    RSSItem item = feed.getItem(position);

    // create an intent
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ItemActivity.class);

    intent.putExtra("pubdate", item.getPubDate());
    intent.putExtra("title", item.getTitle());
    intent.putExtra("description", item.getDescription());
    intent.putExtra("link", item.getLink());

    this.startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

**activity_items.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFAC83"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:text="@string/items_title"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/itemsListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**ItemsFragment.java**

```
package com.murach.newsreader;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ItemsFragment extends Fragment {

private Button testButton;
private TextView titleTextView;
private ListView itemsListView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_items, container,     false);

    testButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.testButton);
    titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
    itemsListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemsListView);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

**fragment_items.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment android:name="com.murach.newsreader.ItemsFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_items"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFAC83"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:text="@string/items_title"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/testButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TEST BUTTON" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/itemsListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**The logcat**

```
<pre>
        at 
    com.murach.newsreader.ItemsFragment.onCreateView(ItemsFragment.java:25)
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2522)
        at 
 android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureInflatedFragmentView(FragmentManager.jav 
   a:1486)
        at 
    android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1269)
        at 
    android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1481)
        at 
    android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1723)
        at 
    android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3556)
        at 
  android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:186 
   )
        at 
    android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
        at 
    android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    02-06 20:45:13.014 4765-4765/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at 
    android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1481)
        at     
    android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1723)
        at     
    android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3556)
        at     
 android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:186    )
        at     
    android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
        at     
    android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at 
    android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at     
    com.murach.newsreader.ItemsFragment.onCreateView(ItemsFragment.java:25)
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2522)
        at     
 android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureInflatedFragmentView(FragmentManager.jav 
   a:1486)
        at     
    android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1269)
        at     
    android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1481)
        at 
    android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1723)
```

The `layoutinflater` should just inflate the fragment xml layout and display the test button and the other widgets. I have tried removing all code irrelevant to inflating the fragment and all code/xml relating to the widgets and it still crashes. I have even created a test project with absolutely nothing but an initial activity with a test button and a fragment with a test button and the `layoutinflater` still won't work.

Comment: What is the stack trace in the logcat tab?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include. Will edit original comment.

Comment: Edited to include logcat

Comment: Ah. You're trying to create `ItemsFragment` inside the layout of `ItemsFragment`, which will then try to create `ItemsFragment` which has a layout that contains `ItemsFragment` which will try to create `ItemsFragment` that will try to create `ItemsFragment` I'm sure you get the idea. Remove the `<fragment` from your layout file.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you. That was the problem. I must have gotten my textbook examples confused because I thought I needed to declare it in the layout.